# Неубиваемый сервис с уведомлением

Tags: android, многопоточность, android-asynctask, service

Есть ооооочень долгий процесс ( ≈ 7 часов) + потребляет много трафика, пока что работает в `AsyncTask`Возможно ли его сделать висяшим в фоне? Охота сервис с уведомлением с прогрессом выполнения. Но у меня вопросы

1. Будет ли он работать все 7 часов если экран заблокирован и все приложения закрыты?
2. Можно ли в сервисе писать без `AsyncTask` и обновлять уведомление напрямую без всяких разделений на потоки и `NetworkOnMainThreadException`?

Comment: Обновил вопрос, где добавил ссылки. Не подскажете, что это за задача такая? :)

Comment: @Rostislav Dugin, скрейпинг сайта :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Однозначно - да. Если, конечно, память не закончится (я про OOM). Используйте [Intent Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) с включенным [startForeground(true)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#startForeground%28int,%20android.app.Notification%29). Данный метод заставит сервис работать на переднем плане и он будет практически идентичен фоновой Activity в плане неубиваемости.
2. Да. Сервису можно выделить отдельный процесс (не поток). Вот тут написано про выделение сервису отдельного процесса - [ссылка на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22514373/start-a-service-in-a-separate-process-android).
3. Не помню, чтобы `Notification` нужен был `UI` поток. Из сервиса у меня всегда работали уведомления.

Comment: Спасибо, буду разбираться, так и думал что `foreground` что-то надо будет)